# Disable message recall in Outlook (2010)

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

Is there a way to disable the message recall button in Outlook 2010? The users do not understand that this works only on the same exchange server and not via the internet. So they often try to recall a message and then they comply that this isn´t/wasn´t working.

So I would like to hide the complete button if possible in outlook (via GPO). But I haven´t found a way so for to do that.

Edit:

I found that [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/delay-your-crabbiness-outlook-features-for-itchy-trigger-fingers-HA010121943.aspx):

> If your recipients have Process requests and responses on arrival selected on their computers (in Outlook: Tools > Options > E-mail Options > Tracking Options), even if the original message — the one you tried to recall — has not been read, the recipient will be notified that something disappeared from their Inboxes. (And boy does that summon up curiosity.)

So it looks like there is no real way to disable that feature fully. But if somebody knows a way to disable that button in outlook, then please share :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable Ribbon interface items in Office applications via Group Policy. There may be keyboard shortcuts or other ways around it, but this will make it more difficult for your users to attempt to recall messages. The specific settings you need are going to be under `User Configuration | Administrative Templates | Microsoft Outlook 2010 | Disable Items in User Interface | Custom | Disable command bar buttons and menu items`. The Control ID for the Recall Message button is 2511 (Control Name: RecallThisMessage).

For reference, you can download the control identifiers for all Office 2010 applications here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627

Comment: Thats nice. I will try to do something in my testlab with the option you mentioned above. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There's not a way to remove the recall button itself within Outlook, short of writing your own custom Outlook interface.

Recall typically doesn't work anyway, even on the same Exchange server, as users often see the email before it is recalled by the system or they can "circumvent" any recall by either using rules to move incoming messages or as you point out if someone unchecks "prces requests and responses on arrival" then they'll have access to both the new and original recalled email.

Honestly, your best bet is to simply explain to people that it won't work as intended (they are hoping the recipient never sees it), but explain that it is best used as a way to notify recipients that the original email was incorrect or inadvertently sent.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/recall-or-replace-an-email-message-that-you-sent-HA010354931.aspx

and on our sister site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226704/email-message-recall-does-it-actually-work

Comment: Explaining people that something they see and can press ... but isn´t working isn´t so easy. They constantly ask to "fix" that. But as you said ... its broken per design. So the only way I see here to fix it finally is to remove it completely. But thanks anyway for your input :).

Comment: Oh, I agree with you.